# TRY/CATCH only reports the last (and most useless) error

Tags: sql-server, backup, error-handling

(This is SQL Server 2016 SP2-CU12.)

When running this command interactively, I see the quite useful `Msg 3035, Level 16, State 1`.

```
BACKUP DATABASE @DB TO DISK = @targetfile
WITH DIFFERENTIAL, RETAINDAYS = 2, COMPRESSION,
NAME = @buname, STATS = 4

Msg 3035, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Cannot perform a differential backup for database "ReportServer", because a current database backup does not exist. Perform a full database backup by reissuing BACKUP DATABASE, omitting the WITH DIFFERENTIAL option.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally
```

But when running it within a TRY/CATCH block, all I get is the Generic `Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1`.  How do I see the specific and useful message `Msg 3035, Level 16, State 1`?  The goal of my task is to test the `ERROR_NUMBER()`, `ERROR_SEVERITY()` and `ERROR_STATE()` values and programmatically perform a full backup when `Msg 3035, Level 16, State 1` occurs, but not when  `Msg 911, Level 16, State 11 Database 'XXX does not exist.` and `Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 Cannot open backup device 'xxxx'. Operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).` errors happen.

```
begin try
    BACKUP DATABASE @DB TO DISK = @targetfile
    WITH DIFFERENTIAL, RETAINDAYS = 2, COMPRESSION,
    STATS = 4
end try
begin catch
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
            ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
            ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
            , ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMsg; 
end catch

ErrorNumber ErrorSeverity ErrorState  ErrorMsg
----------- ------------- ----------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3013        16            1           BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

(1 row affected)
```

Comment: If you need to capture the error without `THROW`, see [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19895/how-to-log-error-details-when-using-using-try-catch-for-dynamic-sql-backup-comma).

Comment: @DanGuzman Thanks; that's very depressing, though.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [THROW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to get the full exception raised:

> If the THROW statement is specified without parameters, it must appear
> inside a CATCH block. This causes the caught exception to be raised.

```
begin try
    BACKUP DATABASE @DB TO DISK = @targetfile
    WITH DIFFERENTIAL, RETAINDAYS = 2, COMPRESSION,
    STATS = 4
end try
begin catch
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
            ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
            ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
            , ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMsg; 
    THROW;
end catch
```

Result

> Msg 3035, Level 16, State 1, Line 8 Cannot perform a differential
> backup for database "...", because a current database backup does
> not exist. Perform a full database backup by reissuing BACKUP
> DATABASE, omitting the WITH DIFFERENTIAL option. Msg 3013, Level 16,
> State 1, Line 8 BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: The goal of my task is to test the `ERROR_NUMBER()`, `ERROR_SEVERITY()` and `ERROR_STATE()` values and programmatically perform a full backup when `Msg 3035, Level 16, State 1` occurs, but not when  `Msg 911, Level 16, State 11 Database 'XXX does not exist.` and `Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 Cannot open backup device 'xxxx'. Operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).` errors happen.  I'll edit the question to mention that.